# Find the value of the variable in the combinatorics.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, combinations

We are given the following inequality:

$$\binom{n}{n/2}>T\;,$$

where $T$ is some fixed value.

How can we find the value of $n$? Do we need to do hit and trial to get the solution or is there any specific way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

According to Stirling's formula one has
$${n\choose n/2}\sim{2^{n+1}\over\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$
for large $n$. Therefore an  approximation of the right order of magnitude would be
$$n>{\log T\over\log2}\ .$$
If you need something more precise you have to solve the equation
$${2^{n+1}\over\sqrt{2\pi n}}=T\ .$$
This can be done in terms of Lamberts $W$-function, which is non-elementary.